# GIMP 2.1 apply gradient to my brush layer

Tags: gimp

I used older version of GIMP and I was able to do this: https://youtu.be/LeHdoQI8xME?t=207

Now with newer version of GIMP, I can't seem to figure how to do that again. I drew abstract image with brush, then select a gradient and color - map - gradient map and it turn the image to yellowish instead of what shown in the video.

Answer (score 0):

*Colors > Map > Gradient Map* works exactly the same in recent versions of GIMP as it did in older versions.

Make sure your image has a range of tones - from black to grey midtones, and bright highlights.  A gradient map can only work properly on an image that has a good range of tones. It wont work well if all your brush strokes are 100% opacity. Also note that everything including the black background needs to be on one layer.

Here's an example (current stable release GIMP 2.10.22). I reduced the brush opacity to about 30%, then painted with different random brushes repeatedly. Then I did a final Levels adjustment to make sure it had a full range of tones.

Here's the levels adjustment I applied, to add more contrast, and below it I've shown the before and after.

[image]

[image]

Here's the before and after, using the "Incandescent" gradient for the gradient map.

[image]